# Missed who vs. Missed whom?

Tags: sentence-construction, subjects, objects

I play online multiplayer game clash of clan. Two native English speakers were talking with each other. The first one showed(appeared?) after some days, and then the other person said:

> Missed who

The speaker is most probably from New Zealand; if not then Canadian for sure. What I am confused about is that I think the correct way should be to say, "*Missed whom*". I can think of sentences like:

- I missed you.
- I missed him.
- I missed whom?
- Whom did I miss?

The *you, him, whom* all are in object form. So, I think correct usage would be *missed whom* not *missed who*?

Is the *who* usage a vernacular, different figurative meaning, or actually the correct usage?

Comment: Many people say who for whom. Who did I miss is very common.

Answer (score 3):

*Whom* is markedly formal and uncommon in normal speech.  In almost all positions, *who* is far more common.  That doesn't mean you'll never see *whom*, but most of the time *who* is the right choice.

So when is *whom* still around?  Well, in particularly formal speech it can be used when you'd have traditionally expected it, but that's not especially common.  You're most likely to see *whom* when it's the object of a fronted preposition, because fronting prepositions is itself markedly formal:

> **To whom** am I speaking?　*(formal)*
>   **Who** am I speaking to?　*(normal)*

But in echo questions, there is a strong preference for *who* no matter what:

> You gave the package to **who**?　*(echo question)*

Your example is also an echo question, so in natural speech *who* is much more likely than *whom*.  To most speakers, *whom* is rather strange in echo questions:

> I missed **who**?　*(echo question)*

Although you can probably find someone who accepts or produces *whom* in this position, they'll be in the minority.

Comment: I still feel perfectly comfortable in the minority.