# Use of Whom or Who in sentences

Tags: word-usage

> She is the one **whom** I love the most.

During an English lesson, this sentence came up and my answer was **whom**. My teacher told me that it is not the best answer (that is who), it is kind of awkward and she would not use it should she say something like this.

Could anybody comment on the use of **whom** in Modern English and how acceptable it is?

Is there any case when **whom** cannot be replaced with **who**, either stylistically or grammatically?

Comment: A  **simple pointer (tip) for you: If the verb is **be**, the pronoun "who" should be used. "Who is he?" "The person **who is** at the door is John."

Comment: Another simple tip: Would you use *he* or *him* in the statement?  If you would use *he*, then use *who*; if you would use *him* then use *whom*.  *I love he*?  No, that's not right, you would say *I love **him***, so it must be "*whom* I love".

Comment: When one is a native speaker with a certain level of education, one intuits when it's best to use whom. There are certain situations where **who** may be used instead of **whom**. That said, I do not consider a sentence like this - "Whom **did you** see?" (did you emphasized) to be stilted. And personally, were it necessary to say in speech "to + whom", I would never say "to+ who" for "To whom did you give it?" Although, I would probably **say**: Who did you give it to?

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/131799/). In some phrases, as the answers suggest, *whom* is preferable, but most of these are already somewhat formal (i.e. the mentioned fronting of a preposition). It's *fossilized* in expressions such as *To whom it may concern* (this is formal and is used in letters), and the LDOCE says: "*Whom* is usually used only in the phrases *one of whom*, *none of whom*, *some of whom* etc." – this is where it doesn't sound stilted/pompous in informal style.

Comment: @Lambie *Whom did you see?* sounds formal and thus stilted in most conversations. I would never recommend that a learner use it. The same goes for *To whom did you give it?*. **To who did you give it?* is simply ungrammatical and consequently isn't used anyway.

Comment: @userr2684291  *"Whom did you see?"* is perfectly fine, as is *"To whom did you give it?"*.   **Whether you should use it** depends on context and culture, as in many grade schools it might get you beat up for your lunch money, but that doesn't mean it's poor grammar.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not saying it's ungrammatical but that, yeah, it might get you beat up for your lunch money.